Subject + verb + personal object + bare infinitive: Can we follow this same formula for all subjunctive verbs?
My main question was prompted when I realized that there were other cases where subjunctive can be used with other verbs, such as with like, ask, etc.
Can we follow this same formula for all subjunctive verbs?

I demanded him pay the bills. (NOT CORRECT; I demanded him to pay the bills.)


I would like her be my friend.


I asked him go to the grocery.


The subject pronouns in English are she and he, not her and him. So it's "I demanded that she pay her taxes," if you're speaking American English.

This question is somewhat unclear; is there a reason why you'd think those sentences with "like" and "ask" are correct?

Does this misunderstanding of mine have a relation to direct and indirect objects?

This question is far too unclear to figure out what exactly you're misunderstanding; it's probably several things, to be honest.

Have you become confused between how to use to-infinitives (like: “I asked her to go", "I asked for her to go") versus how to use that clauses (like "I asked that she go")?  You seem to be struggling with the dropped words, so I'm going to send you to our sister site for learners.

Where did you get the idea of subjunctive for verbs such as like and ask?? One of the forms of what used to be called subjunctive in English is the bare infinitive after certain verbs like: demand, recommend and suggest: I demanded he pay the bills. [no s]. I recommended he leave early, [no s]. https://ellii.com/blog/recommend Also, the verbs like and ask are not involved in this.

The question is:

Subject + verb + personal object + bare infinitive: Can we follow this same formula for all subjunctive verbs?

And the OP suggests three other examples of this pattern:

I demanded him pay the bills

I would like her be my friend

I asked him go to the grocery


As the comments suggest, there may be various questions behind this particular one. But taking it as it stands, the answer is a definite no. None of the four examples are correct, and I'm not sure if the proposed formula would ever produce correct English grammar.
Let's look at an example in detail.

I asked him go to the grocery. This is wrong.
I asked that he go to the grocery." If you want to develop your understanding of the subjunctive this is how you would say it.  That introduces a new clause that tells the reader what I asked. In that clause the subjunctive requires a bare infinitive form of the verb.
I asked him to go to the grocery. This is what I personally would say. It feels to me the simplest version. Here him is the direct object of the verb, and we now use the complete infinitive form of the verb including to.

One final note. With the sentences using demand, you can say " I demanded that he pay the bills", but you cannot say "I demanded him to pay the bills."  This is because in this example demand is intransitive. It does not take a direct object. Speaking grammatically, I can ask you something but I cannot demand you something. We would have to reword the sentence; for example I might demand something of you.

and what difference is there when using "I asked for him to go"

It depends on the context (as it regularly does). It could mean the same thing. But it could imply that you are speaking to a third person. I asked John to go; here I am speaking to John. I asked [the captain] for John to go [with me on the mission]; here John is the one I am asking for, because I think he is the best person to go.

Only for letting this somewhat confusion about the incapacity of using demand with object pronouns +  to-infinitive, why in concrete terms can´t we use it as such?

I think that's already been answered: because demand in your examples is intransitive. It doesn't take a person as a direct object at all. See the last paragraph of my main answer.

If you say is intransitive how come is this phrase written like this " I might demand something of you". The part where it says "demand+something" isn't "something" the direct object of the sentence? As i recall, a transitive verb is that which takes a direct object; as this is represented by not having any preposition preceding it, so as it is in that phrase.

I didn't say that demand is intransitive. I said that it was intransitive in your examples, which is why they were wrong. Obviously if we change the examples, then the discussion would need to take account of that. You are quoting my suggested rewording, and the point of that rewording was to show the changes we needed to make if we used demand transitively.
